# many to many relation in DB on same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm making a database for a languages dictionary. I have a table of definitions with words in diferent languages.

```
DEFINITIONS
-----------
Id
Definition
Language
```

For example some records may be:

```
1->casa->spanish
2->house->english
3->maison->french
...
```

And now I have to create another table for the relationships, but I don't know how to do it correctly. In my application I can have 10 languages more or less. I think two ways of doing this:

```
RELATIONSHIPS
-------------
Id
Id_Spanish
Id_English
Id_French
...
```

So that in the same record I have the word in the different languages. Or this other way:

```
RELATIONSHIPS
-------------
Id
Id_Language_1
Id_Language_2
```

and linking the words in pairs, for example:

```
1(Id) -> 1(Id_Language_1) -> 2(Id_Language_2)
1(Id) -> 1(Id_Language_1) -> 3(Id_Language_2)
...
```

I have read it a lot about relationships many to many, but in my case I think it's better the first option (one record with all the languages), but I'm not very sure. Can someone say they think is best. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would add another column to your primary table

```
DEFINITIONS
-----------
Id
Definition
Language
WordId
```

and assign a word_id to each group to indicate they are all the same word.

```
1->casa->Spanish->10
2->house->English->10
3->maison->French->10
```

Comment: This looks ok if all words only have one meaning.
If meanings are multiple you need either another join table or multiple entries for each word.

Comment: agreed, however, OP never really stated the intention of the data.  If it is being used for translation, then this is the appropriate approach because each word can be grouped by meaning. For instance, Fly would have multiple entries for English.  it doesn't really matter that the words are spelled the same because their translations will not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is definitely better.

- If you add a language, you don't need to change the structure
- Queries for all language pairs are the same. Language ID is a query parameter. This means better query optimization and less code
- Simpler update/delete/insert operations
- Somewhat better support for synonyms

Brian's idea is also good, as long as your words have one meaning and one translation. If they have multiple, it needs to be extended.

Answer (score 0):

Bridge tables only really make sense with dynamic content, your content is static and can easily be defined in rows. Bridge tables require joins which  slow down queries, so I guess one table is what makes the most sense if what you care about is querying speed.

But, what if some words are not defined for all languages. Than you waste a bunch of space on the database, which means it may make sense to use a bridge table.

I am suggesting one really long table with rows like english_word, english_Definition,french_word,french_definition etc...

Answer (score 0):

I've already upvoted Brian's answer but I have enough to add that I think it's worth an additional answer:

Really, stay away from the first idea.  Make lots of overhead to add a new language, and means that you need to either hardcode many different queries, or use dynamically-generated SQL, to make use of that table.

Your second idea, storing pairwise relationships, is better.  At first it might seem harder to write queries against it, but once you get used to it, they will be more general and more straightforward.  However, this design requires you to choose between one of two approaches, either of which has flaws:

- Store every possible pair (English/French, English/Spanish, French/Spanish).  This makes finding any arbitrary translation relatively simply, but requires more storage and allows for the possibility of inconsistencies if you look at more than two languages at a time.  You also need to decide whether to store each pair in both directions; if not the queries become somewhat more complex.
- Store just enough pairs to establish the equivalencies (e.g. store English/French and French/Spanish) then traverse them when necessary to find any given translation.  Simplest way to do this is probably select one language that will always be the first one in each pair (e.g. store Spanish/English and Spanish/French pairs).  But even then, you then need application logic that is aware of which language is the central one.

If you use the design that Brian suggests, any arbitrary translation from one language to another can be done with the same generic query, just plugging in the desired languages and word.